How can I manage to run a single processor project with all processor cores?
import multiprocessing, time
mpCores=multiprocessing.cpu_count()
print("This PC has", mpCores,"cores. Currently only utilising 1, upgrades to follow")

tic = time.perf_counter()                                           # ** Start the timer                                    

exec(open("xxxx.py").read())    # xxxxx
exec(open("xxxxx.py").read())    # xxxxx
exec(open("xxxxxx.py").read())  # xxxxxxx
exec(open("xxxxxxx.py").read())  # xxxxxxxx

toc = time.perf_counter()                                           # ** Stop the timer
print("TOTAL RUN TIME: ", f"{toc - tic:0.2f} seconds")   # the 0.4f means 4 decimal places

As you can see, the code uses a single processor core. My processor is 12 cores. How can I run this process using 12 cores?
I am running a python script. This script calls different python scripts but allows it to run on a single processor

You create a function that takes the filename and executes the exec(open(filename).read()). Then you use the Process class of multithreading to run the function in a new process for each of the filenames. If there are many filenames you can instead look at the concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor class.

If you are going to be reading in the Python file and run it with the exec function, then you would need to use a multiprocessing pool to execute these files in parallel:
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
import multiprocessing
import time


def run_python_file(file_name: str) -> None:
    """Execute Python file as a separate process."""

    with open(file_name) as f:
        return exec(f.read())


def main():
    "Execute multiple Python files in parallel."
    tic = time.perf_counter()

    file_names = [
        "xxxx.py",
        "xxxxx.py",
        "xxxxxx.py",
        "xxxxxxx.py"
    ]

    mp_cores =  multiprocessing.cpu_count()
    pool_size = min(mp_cores, len(file_names))

    with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=pool_size) as executor:
        executor.map(run_python_file, file_names)

    toc = time.perf_counter()
    print("TOTAL RUN TIME: ", f"{toc - tic:0.2f} seconds")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

A Better Way?
I would use the subprocess.run method to execute each Python file. Since this already creates a separate sub-process to execute the Python file, you only need a multithreading pool to be able to run these files in parallel:
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import multiprocessing
import subprocess
import sys
import time


def run_python_file(file_name: str) -> int:
    """Execute Python file as a separate process."""

    completed_process = subprocess.run([sys.executable, file_name])
    return completed_process.returncode


def main():
    "Execute multiple Python files in parallel."
    tic = time.perf_counter()

    file_names = [
        "xxxx.py",
        "xxxxx.py",
        "xxxxxx.py",
        "xxxxxxx.py"
    ]

    mp_cores =  multiprocessing.cpu_count()
    pool_size = min(mp_cores, len(file_names))

    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=pool_size) as executor:
        return_codes = list(executor.map(run_python_file, file_names))
        print(return_codes)

    toc = time.perf_counter()
    print("TOTAL RUN TIME: ", f"{toc - tic:0.2f} seconds")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

